# Finding dispersion relations

Tags: differential-equations, non-linear-systems, dispersion

I was wondering if there is a general (theoretical, not experimental) method for finding the dispersion relation for waves in a medium, say given the equation governing purturbations in the medium? For linear, homogeneous equations (the only type I've come across so far as a second-year physics undergraduate), it is clear you can simply substitute in a general sinusoid/exponential form to obtain this, however it is not clear to me how to approach this for non-linear and/or inhomogeneous equations.

Comment: This wikipedia article may be a good starting point for further research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averaged_Lagrangian#Connection_to_the_dispersion_relation

Answer (score 1):

I think the exact methods depend on the type of system. The simplest system is probably gases with one free electron. [Here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/wwe/EIT_Wes_Erickson_Thesis_2012.pdf) you can find how the dipole moment of the polarizability of the neucleus+electron changes when light is shined on this gas-light system. The you can see how this varies when changing the frequency of light (giving you a dispersion relation).